# Node.js / Backbone async or not?

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, asynchronous

In my node.js backbone app, I am iterating over the collection and performing calculations on each model upon page load.  Each function grabs different variables to perform the calculations and saves the model through a restful api.  Now my thought is that the code below is too 'expensive' on page load and resources.  But is this handled asynchronously or would it be better if I combined them both into one function?

```
render: function() {
  this.trigger('calculateSpread'); 
  this.trigger('checkClose'); 
}

calculateSpread: function() {
  stocks.models.forEach(function(model) {
    var x = this.model.get('')....
    .....calculations
    this.model.save()
}

checkClose: function() {
  stocks.models.forEach(function(model) {
    var x = this.model.get('')....
    .....calculations
    this.model.save()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the trigger event is synchronous. Source:

```
trigger: function(name) {
  if (!this._events) return this;
  var args = slice.call(arguments, 1);
  if (!eventsApi(this, 'trigger', name, args)) return this;
  var events = this._events[name];
  var allEvents = this._events.all;
  if (events) triggerEvents(this, events, args);
  if (allEvents) triggerEvents(this, allEvents, arguments);
  return this;
},
```

The import function is triggerEvents, it's looks like an optimised dispatcher. Notice that they're all calling `.call()` and `.apply()`, so the callback will complete before control is handed back to the caller.

```
var triggerEvents = function(obj, events, args) {
    var ev, i = -1, l = events.length;
    switch (args.length) {
    case 0: while (++i < l) (ev = events[i]).callback.call(ev.ctx);
    return;
    case 1: while (++i < l) (ev = events[i]).callback.call(ev.ctx, args[0]);
    return;
    case 2: while (++i < l) (ev = events[i]).callback.call(ev.ctx, args[0], args[1]);
    return;
    case 3: while (++i < l) (ev = events[i]).callback.call(ev.ctx, args[0], args[1], args[2]);
    return;
    default: while (++i < l) (ev = events[i]).callback.apply(ev.ctx, args);
    }
};
```

Thus, whether or not the handlers will be 'expensive' is dependent on the handler code itself.

Answer (score 1):

I think combining them would be better so it won't save twice for each model and it'll be cleaner too. This should happen synchronously unless your calculations part does async work (ajax)

```
render: function() {
  this.trigger('calculate'); 
}

calculate: function () {
    stocks.models.forEach(function(model) {
        this.calculateSpread(model);
        this.checkClose(model);
        this.model.save()
    }
}

calculateSpread: function(model) {
    var x = model.get('')....
    ...calculations
}

checkClose: function(model) {
    var x = model.get('')....
    .....calculations
}
```